# undefined method `database_authenticatable' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Briefing: I've been attempting to deploy my blog to heroku for the last week with no luck. I've contacted Heroku support and they've pretty much told me to post the log on stackoverflow. So here I am.

Look's like there is some sort of database authentication error, but I'm having toruble pin-pointing it. Anyway here's the codebase: www.github.com/apane/blogit_blog.

Heroku log below.

Gemfile provided for good measure:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'blogit', '0.8.0'

gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.4"

gem 'devise'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem "unicorn", "~> 4.6.2"

end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg'
  gem "unicorn", "~> 4.6.2"

end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'  
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
Rake db:migrate error log:
```

Heroku log:

```
rake aborted!
    An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

    undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x007fefbccaad60>/Users/anthonypanepinto/Sites/personal_blog/personal_blog/db/migrate/20130529023532_devise_create_users.rb:4:in `block in up'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:160:in `create_table'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
    /Users/anthonypanepinto/Sites/personal_blog/personal_blog/db/migrate/20130529023532_devise_create_users.rb:3:in `up'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `up'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you upgrade to Devise 2 without going back and changing your original Devise migration?

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style